# get_post_field - Title without paragraph

Tags: posts, title

Normally I wouldn't insert a single post with a technique like this, but sadly this project requires it.

I try to call the `post_title` with:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) );
```

The problem is, that this code will display the title inside a paragraph like:

```
<p>Title</p>
```

How can I block it out, or even replace it with an `h2`?

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you using shortcodes in titles?

Comment: Why `the_content` and not `the_title` ? `the_content` uses [`wpautop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) which will add those paragraphs. But, You could use regex to replace `p` with `h2`

Comment: @SamuelElh thank you, this is the solution. Single posts are confusing me. This was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion

[`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) is not a proper hook for filtering post titles while it filters the post content. [`wpautop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) function is called with `the_content` so it adds the necessary paragraphs.

To filter post titles use [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) instead, it won't add any markup tags by default:

```
echo apply_filters('the_title', get_post_field('post_title', $post_id));
```

Comment: No worries. Have a good day!